# How do I customize the welcome screen in Emacs

Tags: emacs, customization

So how would I go about customizing the welcome screen? I know about `initial-buffer-choice`, but I'd like to customize the original one as a part of theme (I'm working on a Tron theme, and wanted to have all bits of it perfect!).

I don't want to change the text, but I have an alternative design for the logo :) It's not really a replacement, and I'm not going to put a *different* logo instead, it's just a minor remake to go with the color theme.

**EDIT:** below is what I've got so far :)

[image: a thumbnail of the complete desktop]

And the larger image:

[image]

**EDIT**

Sorry for making you wait. Here we go: https://code.google.com/p/tron-theme-emacs/ If you find a language mode where the theme misbehaves, I will try to fix it. I think I tried it once on a text terminal, rather than X-window Emacs, but I don't remember how it was. So, that may be a problem. Also, some modes may come with their own faces. I tried to set some (like ECB), but these may not be complete / I'm not aware of all the possible faces. But, again, request for improvements are welcome.

Comment: this looks awesome!! Is the theme ready? Will it be available for everyone or is it only for yourself?

Comment: Thanks, that would be awesome. I would be one of the first to download the theme/skin, you can count on that.

Comment: @wvxvw Does this theme exist now? It would look really cool. Some Daft Punk music and ready to get to work...

Comment: @wvxvw It'll be very much appreciated. How much of this is reality so far? Shiny frame the logo? Props.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change splash image, set `fancy-splash-image`.
To change text and color, set `fancy-startup-text` and `fancy-about-text`.